# Avoiding a for loop when using apply on each row of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I am writing a script which identifies the interval that a vector of numbers fall between. e.g. 0.3 falls in the first interval of 0.5, 0.8, 1. A simplified example of the code below:

```
df <- data.frame(p1 = runif(10)/2, p2 = rep(-1,10), p3 = rep(1, 10));
df$p2 <- df$p1 + runif(10)/2;
r <- runif(10);

c(1,2,3)[apply(abs(outer(as.numeric(df[1,]), r, '-')),2, which.min)];
```

This works well when each value in r is applied to the same vector - in this case as.numeric(df[1,]).  However, I now need to apply each value in r to its corresponding unique row in the dataset df.  At the moment I am doing this in a loop, which seems inefficent, but I have been unable to find an efficient  alterative to looping through each row:

```
a <- array(dim=10);
for(x in 1:10){
    a[x] <- c(1,2,3)[apply(abs(outer(as.numeric(df[x,]), r[x], '-')),2, which.min)];
}
```

Is there a more efficient alternative than a loop?

Thanks,
James

Comment: `?findInterval` rather than your own function. It's written in C so it will probably be much more efficient than your implementation. You'll still need to call it on each line individually.

Comment: ending lines with `;` in R is discouraged.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, the combination of findInterval and mutate seems to work very efficiently in my actual code.  I will convert the code I have to use dplyr rather than the current matrix.

Answer (score 0):

As @Gregor mentioned, it's better to use `findInterval`. You can use `mutate_xxx` functions from the `dplyr` package to apply `findInterval` on all columns

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1111)
df <- data.frame(p1 = runif(10)/2, p2 = rep(-1,10), p3 = rep(1, 10));
df$p2 <- df$p1 + runif(10)/2;

# define intervals
intv1 <- c(0.3, 0.5, 0.8, 1) 

# columns start with `p`
df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("p")), funs(bin = findInterval(., intv1)))
#>            p1        p2 p3 p1_bin p2_bin p3_bin
#> 1  0.23275132 0.2335964  1      0      0      4
#> 2  0.20646243 0.5809412  1      0      2      4
#> 3  0.45350161 0.8289807  1      1      3      4
#> 4  0.06855271 0.3852559  1      0      1      4
#> 5  0.36940842 0.8034923  1      1      3      4
#> 6  0.48816350 0.5678450  1      1      2      4
#> 7  0.43997997 0.8983940  1      1      3      4
#> 8  0.05839214 0.3368955  1      0      1      4
#> 9  0.27314439 0.7233537  1      0      2      4
#> 10 0.07005799 0.4530015  1      0      1      4

# selected columns only
col2select <- c("p1", "p2")
df %>% 
  mutate_at(col2select, funs(bin = findInterval(., intv1)))
#>            p1        p2 p3 p1_bin p2_bin
#> 1  0.23275132 0.2335964  1      0      0
#> 2  0.20646243 0.5809412  1      0      2
#> 3  0.45350161 0.8289807  1      1      3
#> 4  0.06855271 0.3852559  1      0      1
#> 5  0.36940842 0.8034923  1      1      3
#> 6  0.48816350 0.5678450  1      1      2
#> 7  0.43997997 0.8983940  1      1      3
#> 8  0.05839214 0.3368955  1      0      1
#> 9  0.27314439 0.7233537  1      0      2
#> 10 0.07005799 0.4530015  1      0      1

# for all columns
df %>% 
  mutate_all(funs(bin = findInterval(., intv1)))
#>            p1        p2 p3 p1_bin p2_bin p3_bin
#> 1  0.23275132 0.2335964  1      0      0      4
#> 2  0.20646243 0.5809412  1      0      2      4
#> 3  0.45350161 0.8289807  1      1      3      4
#> 4  0.06855271 0.3852559  1      0      1      4
#> 5  0.36940842 0.8034923  1      1      3      4
#> 6  0.48816350 0.5678450  1      1      2      4
#> 7  0.43997997 0.8983940  1      1      3      4
#> 8  0.05839214 0.3368955  1      0      1      4
#> 9  0.27314439 0.7233537  1      0      2      4
#> 10 0.07005799 0.4530015  1      0      1      4
```

Created on 2018-05-08 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions.  I have used dplyr and come up with the following.  It seems quicker than my original, but still suffers as the size of the dataset increases:

```
 library(dplyr);

 # Dummy data-set
 nRows <- 1000
 df <- data.frame(p1 = runif(nRows )/2, p2 = rep(-1,nRows ), p3 = rep(1, nRows ), r = runif(nRows))
 df$p2 <- df$p1 + runif(nRows )/2

df %>% dplyr::rowwise() %>%
       dplyr::mutate_at(vars(starts_with("r")), funs(bin = 1+findInterval(., c(p1,p2,p3))))
```

-- James